# Xamarin Forms inTune SDK integration

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, intune

I am fairly new to Azure ecosystem & Xamarin Forms. I am using this guide to integrate an Xamarin Forms app with inTune: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/app-sdk-xamarin#enabling-mam-in-your-android-mobile-app

I am not sure if i understand correctly, but the guide mentions "components" which are replaced by Nuget in Xamarin (Source: https://blog.xamarin.com/hello-nuget-new-home-xamarin-components/).

so my question is:
Are "components" still a viable solution in Xamarin. Shouldn't we just install a package from Nuget and get it over with?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As your link points out, Components are being deprecated in favor of Nuget packages.  If you have a choice, use a Nuget package.

Comment: the problem is that page was updated by Microsoft on not more than 2 months ago. So fairly new. Are they trying to confuse us?